# Count grandchild nodes in a cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have the following data structure:

```
/users
    /{user_uid}
        /lists
            /{list_uid}
```

Using a cloud function, i'd like to be able to have a `/list_count` reference on the root of my database, to be able to easily track list count without having to do a fat client-side call to count them.

at the moment I have this implementation, which I find a bit ugly:

```
exports.countlists = functions.database.ref('/users/{uuid}/lists').onWrite(event => {
    const ref = event.data.ref.parent.parent.parent.child('list_count');

    return ref.transaction(current => {
        if (event.data.exists() && !event.data.previous.exists()) {
            return (current || 0) + 1;
        }
        else if (!event.data.exists() && event.data.previous.exists()) {
            return (current || 0) - 1;
        }
    });
});
```

The issue being that I get an error in the firebase console:

> Error serializing return value: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Inlined said [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/193):

*The problem you're running into is that the promised value that ref.transaction returns isn't serializeable as JSON. The easiest way to fix this (before we fix it in the Firebase SDK) is to transform the value to something like null.*

I think to fix your problem, do this:

```
exports.countlists = functions.database.ref('/users/{uuid}/lists').onWrite(event => {
let root = admin.database().ref(`users/${event.params.uuid}/lists/list_count`)

    return root.transaction(function(current){
        if (event.data.exists() && !event.data.previous.exists()) {
            return (current || 0) + 1;
        }
        else{
            return (current || 0) - 1;
        }
    }.then(() => null));
});
```

Comment: I added a console.log at the end of the chain, as console.log returns null, it works. But the data is not modified at the reference, so the problem is not fixed :/

Comment: @Supamiu please copy paste my code now, maybe your ref variable was not good.

Comment: The ref I want to write on is `/list_count`, starting from root. But I get your point, changing for a direct reference using admin.database(). let me change that and I'll accept if it resolves the problem, else I'll edit this comment :)

Comment: I added a console.log(current) in the transaction process and even if I manually set /list_count to 0 in the database, I still get `null` as `current` value. (couldn't edit, too slow)

Comment: @Supamiu I am sorry I thought your function was working, but when looking at my own code I think you were something missing. Now this updated code should work :D

Comment: I used onCreate() and onDelete() listeners and it works fine. Because you solved the error I was getting in the question, I'll accept your answer.